# How can i Add the export path for swift into ./profile on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, swift

Single use:

```
 export PATH = $ PATH:/home/raul/swift/usr/ bin
```

but When the terminal restarts the configuration is lost but in the ~/.profile the same line is not working u.u

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code below can be added to the end of `.profile`.  Review to make sure there are no spaces the path strings `/home/raul/swift/usr/bin` and `PATH="$PATH:/home/raul/swift/usr/bin"`.

```sh
## :MY:PROFILE:EDIT: add swift executable path
if [ -d "/home/raul/swift/usr/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$PATH:/home/raul/swift/usr/bin"
fi
```

After `.profile` is edited, do one to the following for the changes to take affect:

- `source .profile`
- logout and re-login to the desktop session
- restart the machine

Note: `.profile` would be effective to the duration of the desktop login session and for subsequent terminal sessions within the same desktop session. `.bashrc` would typically apply just to the scope of a terminal session.